# Is arbitrary direct sum of vector spaces vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suddenly thinking about arbitrary direct sum of the real numbers R, I came across this question. Can someone answer this?

Comment: The answer is *yes*.

Comment: Yes, it is... *if the factors are vector spaces over the same field* . Whether you're thinking of internal direct sum (of subspaces of some space) or external one with the obvious definition, it is always a linear space

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The title of a question should not be its first sentence.